# Backbone application: storing user settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I have been recently working on a rails/backbone application. Until now, any time a user made some specific changes to the application (e.g. chose one view over others, used certain filters, customized the information presented in the view), I would store his/her choices into rails session variables. Using the information from these session variables ensured that the user's changes persist when the page refreshes or when new instances of the application are used on the same computer. This is the case until the user signs out, which leads to the loss of the session variables' information and to default settings the next time the user logs in.

The received feedback was that users actually want their changes to persist even if they log out or if they use different computers (e.g. the default settings should be replaced by their changes, as long as the same user is logged in). How should I implement this feature?

Thank you!

Comment: You should save the data in a database instead of in a session.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Mischa, you should save the datas in database.

This is an exemple how to simple add preferences to an user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences
end

u = User.new
u.preferences = {
   :view => {:controller => :dasboard, :action => :index}, 
   :filters => {
      :users => {
         :order => :email
         :page => 1
         :quantity_per_page => 20
      }
   }
}
```

Make sure that field's type in database is an "Text"